# Calculating Terrain Ruggedness in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to recreate Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI) in Google Earth Engine. The formula I am trying to create is below:

*Compute s = Focal sum (over 3 x 3 square neighborhoods) of [DEM].
Compute DEM2 = [DEM]*[DEM].
Compute t = Focal sum (over 3 x 3 square neighborhoods) of [DEM2].
Compute r2 = [t] + 9*[DEM2] - 2*[DEM]*[s].
Return r = Sqrt([r2]).*

However, when I try to calculate on GEE I get odd results. My script is found below and in the link:

```
var Sum = DEM.reduceNeighborhood({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
kernel: ee.Kernel.rectangle(3,3),
}).rename('Sum');
 var DEM2 = DEM.expression(
    '(DEM*DEM)', {
      'DEM': DEM.select('DEM'),
  }).rename('DEM2');
var t = DEM2.reduceNeighborhood({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
kernel: ee.Kernel.rectangle(3,3),
});

var image = Sum.addBands(DEM.rename('DEM'))
                              .addBands(DEM2.rename('DEM2'))
                              .addBands(t.rename('t'));
print(image, "image")

//compute TRI equation (Riley et al., 1999)
 var r2 = image.expression(
     '(t+9*DEM2-2*DEM*Sum)', {
      't': image.select('t'),
      'DEM2': image.select('DEM2'),
      'DEM': image.select('DEM'),
      'Sum': image.select('Sum'),
  }).rename('r2');   
 
print(r2, "r2)")
var image = r2.addBands;
var TRI =  r2.sqrt
print(TRI,"TRI")
Map.addLayer(r2)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e2aad7fb6b77c490823efe20ec07e57e

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have success with a different formula that I have seen floating around on the internet. The formula I used was:

```
  SquareRoot(Abs((Square(Focal_Max(DEM,3,3)) - Square(Focal_Min(DEM,3,3)))))

Update script here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/380496d4677ff9d2d728bf59a285c978

//VERSION 2/

var MaxDEM = DEM.focalMax(3,'square').rename('MaxDEM')

print(MaxDEM, "MaxDEM")
var MaxDEM = MaxDEM.expression(
     '(MaxDEM)*(MaxDEM)', {
      'MaxDEM': MaxDEM.select('MaxDEM')}).rename('MaxDEM')
      print(MaxDEM, "MaxDEM")
      Map.addLayer(MaxDEM)
  
var MinDEM = DEM.focalMin(3,'square').rename('MinDEM')
var MinDEM = MinDEM.expression(
     '(MinDEM)*(MinDEM)', {
      'MinDEM': MinDEM.select('MinDEM')}).rename('MinDEM')   
    var image = MaxDEM.addBands(MinDEM)
    
    print(image, "image")

var a = MaxDEM.subtract(MinDEM).reproject({crs: 'EPSG: 26920',
scale: 5});
  var TRI = a.sqrt().rename('TRI')
  var VizParam = {min:-16.57, max:113.4, palette: ['white', 'black']}
  Map.addLayer(TRI,VizParam, 'TRI')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't address the GEE code specifically but, I am curious as to where the two equations came from? I have an implementation of TRI, in the R spatialEco library, that reflects the original Riley et al., (1999) equation as well as a fairly precise algebraic approximation. Riley's TRI is the square root of the summed deviations and represent a fairly clear measure of ruggedness throughout the literature.

At first blush, the OP's workflow and what @Erioderma proposes do not clearly approximate the original TRI metric, both numerically nor in spatial pattern (figure 1). The OP's implementation results in a very long tailed distribution with a contracted region representing the actual ruggedness (figure 2 - Proposed Eq. 1). However, I will note that if you truncate the metric resulting from Eq. 1 to 2500, the results look much more promising but, one still has to question the math that creates the long tails and there are some undesirable artifacts (eg., high values at No Data boundaries). The @Erioderma solution does return a similar distribution to TRI but, creates a spread in the process (figure 2 - Proposed Eq. 2) thus, changing the spatial pattern and magnitude of the metric. Given your application, this may not matter and remain relative to the process but, it is striking me as a bit over dispersed.

It may be prudent to evaluate each approach against your intended use.

Figure 1. Maps of four methods showing differing spatial patterns.

[image: maps of 4 methods]

Figure 2. Distributions (PDF's) of four methods illustrating different statistical distributions.

[image: distributions of 4 methods]

Figure 3. Results of truncating Eq. 1 results to 2500.

[image: truncated Eq. 1]

Here is the R code behind the above evaluation

```
library(spatialEco)
library(terra)

dem <- rast(system.file("extdata/elev.tif", package="spatialEco"))

# Original and Algerbric approximation
( tri1 <- spatialEco::tri(dem, exact=TRUE) )
( tri2 <- spatialEco::tri(dem, exact=FALSE)  )

# Proposed Eq. 1 
# s = 3x3 focal sum of DEM 
# dem2 = dem * dem
# t = 3x3 focal sum of dem2
# tri = sqrt( t + 9 * dem2 - 2 * dem * s )
s <- terra::focal(dem, w=3, fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE) 
dem2 <- dem * dem
t <- terra::focal(dem2, w=3, fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE)  
( tri3 <- sqrt(t + 9 * dem2 - 2 * dem * s) )

# Proposed Eq. 2
# SquareRoot(Abs((Square(Focal_Max(DEM,3,3)) - Square(Focal_Min(DEM,3,3)))))
tri.calc <- function(ymin, ymax) sqrt( abs(ymax^2 - ymin^2) ) 
rmin <- terra::focal(dem, w=3, fun=min, na.rm=TRUE) 
rmax <- terra::focal(dem, w=3, fun=max, na.rm=TRUE)
( tri4 <- tri.calc(rmin, rmax) )

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  plot(tri1, main="Original (range 0 - 2288.314)", 
       legend=FALSE)
  plot(tri2, main="Algebraic approximation (range 0 - 2288.313)", 
       legend=FALSE)
  plot(tri3.2, main="Proposed Eq. 1  (range 0.011 - 10242.949)", 
       legend=FALSE)
  plot(tri4, main="Proposed Eq. 2  (range 0 - 3024.996)", 
       legend=FALSE)
       
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  d1 <- density(tri1[!is.na(tri1[])][,1])
  plot(d1, main="Original", type="n",  
       xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
    polygon(d1, col="blue")        
  d2 <- density(tri2[!is.na(tri2[])][,1])
  plot(d2, main="Algebraic approximation", 
       type="n", xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
    polygon(d2, col="blue")     
  d3 <- density(tri3[!is.na(tri3[])][,1])
  plot(d3, main="Proposed Eq. 1", 
       type="n", xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
    polygon(d3, col="blue") 
  d4 <- density(tri4[!is.na(tri4[])][,1])
  plot(d4, main="Proposed Eq. 2", 
       type="n", xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
    polygon(d4, col="blue") 


tri3.2 <- ifel(tri3 > 2500, NA, tri3)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
  plot(tri3.2, main="Proposed Eq. 1")
  d3 <- density(tri3.2[!is.na(tri3.2[])][,1])
  plot(d3, main=NA, 
       type="n", xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
    polygon(d3, col="blue")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this research Jeffrey! This is very informative and I think for my purposes (using as a variable to predict wetlands, the formula I am using should suffice.). But I have also developed a raster using an application on QGIS so I will compare the results. 

Thanks for the R code. I am just learning R so I will plug that in as practice. Thanks again!